# Polychoric regression significance test

Tags: r

I have Likert type data, some 4-point scale and others 3-point scale.  For example:

```
variable.x <- c(5,2,4,5,3,1)
variable.y <- c(0,1,1,0,2,1)

my.data <- cbind(variable.x, variable.y)

library(psych)
polychoric(my.data)

#Call: polychoric(x = my.data)
#Polychoric correlations 
#           vrbl.x vrbl.y
#variable.x  1.00        
#variable.y -0.25   1.00 

# with tau of 
#               0     1   2    3   4
#variable.x -0.97 -0.43   0 0.43 Inf
#variable.y -0.43  0.97 Inf  Inf Inf
```

How can I obtain a significance value for the correlation of -0.25?

Strangely the use of the `polycor` package gives totally different results:

```
library(polycor)
polychor(variable.x, variable.y, ML=TRUE, std.err=TRUE)

#Polychoric Correlation, ML est. = -0.7599 (0.2588)
#Test of bivariate normality: Chisquare = 9.088, df = 7, p = 0.2464

#  Row Thresholds
#  Threshold Std.Err.
#1   -0.9388   0.5519
#2   -0.5774   0.5040
#3   -0.1906   0.5267
#4    0.3979   0.5690


 #  Column Thresholds
 #  Threshold Std.Err.
 #1   -0.3891   0.5683
 #2    0.9692   0.5568
```

Now the correlation coefficient is -0.76 now, not -0.25.  Again, how would I find its significance?

Comment: I think this is perhaps better placed on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) as i think it is more geared towards statistical advice.

Comment: Just a quick point - different packages and software use different algorithms for calculating polychoric / tetrachoric correlations. Also one difference here is that `polychoric` adds a continuity correction to account for zero cell counts. If you remove it - `polychoric(my.data, correct=FALSE)` you get more similar correlations. It is a statistical decision if you should use the correction.

Comment: Also, i would imagine these differences between methods are more pronounced for small samples (n=6 in your case). Try rerunning it with `variable.x <- sample(1:5, 100, T) ;variable.y <- sample(1:5, 100, T)`. The correlations and thresholds are much more similar.